# Call Math functions without writing Math.__ every time?

Tags: javascript

I have some code that uses JavaScript’s Math functions quite a lot, to the point that I’d much rather be writing things like `exp(cos(PI/2))` instead of `Math.exp(Math.cos(Math.PI/2))`, which gets ugly and unreadable fast. Even an alias like `m.` would be clutter. To that extent, I need a simple bit of header code to enumerate over Math and pull its entries into the current scope.

Comment: `this` should never be used in global scope. This doesn’t work in modern JS. Use `globalThis` instead. Also, please see [Etiquette for answering your own question](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/289905). Your _question_ must not already contain the answer.

Comment: Cool, never heard of `globalThis` before, thank you!! And thank you for the link, I wasn’t sure, it’s my first post and I wanted to make it clear that I attempted a solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
console.log("With the prefix: " + Math.exp(Math.cos(Math.PI/3)));

const { exp, cos, PI } = Math;
console.log("Without prefix:  " + exp(cos(PI/3)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpfulness, my posted answer has been by far the best solution for me though! I had previously been declaring every function like you’re suggesting, and wanted to stop doing that. I was trying to be kind and posted it for everyone to use and enjoy as much as I have been (it’s very wonderful for anyone live-coding visuals) but honestly haven’t had a pleasant experience on this post and someone just antagonistically edited it and my others. Truly don’t know why my answer has a negative rating, anyone who’s experienced this situation would immediate recognize the elegance of it.

Comment: Your posted solution works, but with the downside of polluting the globalThis object, possibly even overwriting functions or properties that it already had. The downvote may have been done as a warning "don't do this" both to you and others.

Answer (score -2):

Posted above!

```js
// Import all Math numbers and functions to the current (global) scope.
for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math))
  globalThis[name] = Math[name]

console.log(  exp(cos(PI/2))  )  // = 1
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/haumed/pen/YzvwbMP)

Comment: This *only* works in global scope in the browser. If this code is in a function, it would be quite unpredictable, as it would depend on the value of `this` when the function is executed. Best case scenario is `this = undefined` which means it *only* throws an error immediately. It might actually be worse if `this` points to an object since it will alter the object which has a chance of injecting unpredictable behaviour when that object is handled. But then the function would still throw an error because `exp` and `cos` and `PI` aren't valid identifiers in scope.

Comment: No I just tested, works fine in both classic `function() {  }` and fat arrow `() => {  }` notations to pull into that current scope, even though they have different `this`’s. Not my use case anyway though, it’s only intended to be written once at the top-level.

Comment: Also, `this` should never be undefined anyway, but Sebastian’s suggestion of `globalThis` above is beautiful, editing my answer to reflect that!

Comment: It will work in a classic function when : 1. it's running in loose mode 2. it's called in the global scope 3. the value of `this` is not changed. For arrow function it will work *only* if the arrow function is defined in global scope and it's in loose mode. That's a lot of conditionals to clear for "just works". Any of these can be defined in a module. Or inside another function. Or in a myriad of other situations.

Comment: "*Also, this should never be undefined anyway*" it is `undefined` in strict mode which is the only real way you should be running your code. All ES6+ constructs enforce strict mode by default - generators, modules, classes, async functions, etc. But even if you use, say, a module bundler, often the configuration is to emit strict mode code: https://jsbin.com/lihadilimo/1/edit?js,console